# How to pass updated array object to parent component from child component in reactJs

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am add, editing, updating and removing array elements in my component that is working perfectly.

Problem is that I am not able to do the same process for parent component because I need to pass that array data to parent component.

An array got item in child component ( send that item to parent component array too )

A update ( update actual one item but similar object in parent component array too )

Same goes for delete too.

I am unable to update the parent array while doing all this in child component.

I want to have updated array in my parent component.
Below is the code.

**Child Component:**

```
// child component saving element in an array
    saveLeadPlanDialog = () => {

        const {updateMode, lead_id, year, probability, plan2, plan3, fee, addcosts} = this.state;

        // here i am setting that data in child component
        this.setState(state => ({
            lead_plans: [...state.lead_plans, {
                id: Date.now(),
                year: year,
                probability: probability,
                plan2: plan2,
                plan3: plan3,
                fee: fee,
                addcosts: addcosts
            }]
        }));

        // here i am sending that data to parent component.
        this.props.plansClick({
                id: Date.now(),
                year: year,
                probability: probability,
                plan2: plan2,
                plan3: plan3,
                fee: fee,
                addcosts: addcosts
            }
        );
    }

// here i am doing delete process in child component
handleRemoveFields = () => {
        const {updateMode, lead_plan_row} = this.state;
        this.setState(prevState => ({lead_plans: prevState.lead_plans.filter(lead_offer_rec => lead_offer_rec !== lead_plan_row)}));
    };

// updating in child component
const {lead_id, lead_plans, year, probability, plan2, plan3, fee} = this.state;
            const new_lead = {
                id: lead_id,
                year,
                probability,
                plan2,
                plan3,
                fee,
            };
            const updated_lead_plans = lead_plans.map((lead) => lead.id === lead_id ? new_lead : lead);
            this.setState({
                lead_plans: updated_lead_plans,
                year: '',
                probability: '',
                plan2: '',
                plan3: '',
                fee: '',
                addcosts: '',
                newFieldsEditMode: false,
                LeadPlanSaveUpdateDialogOpen: false
            });
```

**Parent Component:**

```
 // parent component method.
    handlePlansClick = (planData) => {
        // this is parent componet, here i need to do update, delete the array object which got updation and deletion in child component
        // it alwaya adds item right now.
        this.setState(state => ({
            lead_plans: [...state.lead_plans, planData]
        }));
    }
```

I need to do all these processes in my parent component too.

Is there more good way to deal with such situation?

How I can get updated, edited, removed item and operation in parent component too?

So both child and parent show the same array component data in arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You should apply a single source of truth principle here. Update the data in the parent only (using a callback passed to the child, as you're doing currently), and then pass the result as a prop to the child. This way the data will always be in sync in both components.

EDIT:

```
 // parent component method.
    handlePlansClick = (planData) => {
        // this is parent componet, here i need to do update, delete the array object which got updation and deletion in child component
        // it alwaya adds item right now.
        this.setState(state => ({
            lead_plans: [...state.lead_plans, planData]
        }));
    }
```

Now you pass this function to the child as a prop along with the data:

```
<Child handlePlansClick={this.handlePlansClick} lead_plans={this.state.lead_plans}/>
```

Don't use the child's state, just the `lead_plans` passed from the parent.

BTW, you should be using `camelCase` for the variable names.

Comment: By I am doing the operations from child component, how I can update data in parent only? Can you give code example?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Comment: Bear with my lack of knowledge, but at which place i will be doing edit, update, delete work? Also how I can pass the updated data back to parent? Can you explain a bit please?

Comment: You don't technically pass the data up to the parent. You pass the parent's method (`handlePlansClick`) down to the child and then you call it in the child component (`this.props.handlePlansClick(newData)`) passing the new data as the argument. The data mutation will happen in the parent only, the child will just get the result as a prop.

Answer (score 1):

To pass data from child to parent you can write code like below and you will get data in parent.

```
 Class Child {
        const passDataToParent =() =>{
           const sampleObj = {"name": "Xyz","contact":98739793};
           this.props.receiveChildData(sampleObj );
        }; 
 } 



Class Parent{
    const storeChildData = (dataReceivedFromChild) =>{
         console.log("Received child data",storeChildData)
    }

    render(){
       return (<Child receiveChildData={this.storeChildData}>);
    }
 }
```

Comment: I am already doing it with more different way, problem is that I need to sycn both arrays at one time!!! My child work is working fine but I need to update everything in same manner in my parent component too!!!

Comment: As I said, you don't need to sync anything. Keep the entire state in the parent component and pass the relevant parts of it to the child as props.

Comment: @LearningROR if you don't want to do same process at both places then you can use below 2 ways.
1) pass updated data from child to parent.
2) use redux and on any action, you need to update data on the redux store and on redux store update you will get updated data in the parent component.

Comment: How to go for #2? I used redux only for getting api calls and stuff like that. How to get work from it in this regard?

Comment: Also as I am passing values from child to parent, but I am not getting updated things in parent. As at both places I am incrementing my lead_plans using ... operator.

Comment: The goal here was to update both states at once! Or a best practice way to get that done. Because I am having trouble in passing updating data to parent as in parents I am already incrementing array object which do not tell me which to delete, which to update. Does that make sense?

Comment: @LearningROR For #2 way, you need to connect both your child and parent component to redux and once you will call any action to update data in redux store and on completion of that action, mapStateProps method will trigger and there you will get updated data.

Comment: @LearningROR as you know ES6 concept, you can pass which fields you changed in a child, and in Parent using spread operator you can override the value of the child component field which is only changed.

Comment: Sharing data between a component and its direct child is not a valid use case for redux.

Comment: Then in this case, I dont need redux to do this small job!